# Manipulating elements of a dict of counters without using double for loop (preferably list comprehension)

Tags: python-3.x, counter

so I have a dict which takes in strings as keys and maps them to counters of `string->count` which looks something like the following:

```
defaultdict(collections.Counter,
            {'': Counter({'<S>': 2,
                      '=': 2,
                      'chronicles': 1,
                      'iii': 1,
                      'no': 1,
                      'senjō': 1,
                      'valkyria': 2}),
             '<S>': Counter({'<S>': 1, '=': 1}),
             '<S> <S>': Counter({'=': 1}),
```

So the only way I am able to do this is by doing a double for loop of accessing the strings and then accessing the values of a counter and dividing by the sum of the values of that respective counter. An example: `s` is just a list of all the strings in the dict, and then I find the sum of the values of the counter at that string, and then I loop again through the keys dividing them by `sum_val`.

```
for s in voc:  
  sum_val = sum(lm[s].values())
  for k in lm[s].keys():
    lm[s][k] = lm[s][k]/sum_val
```

The problem with this approach is that it's taking too much time (never really got output to show for large dataset); does anyone have a different approach (maybe list comprehension)? I am not quite sure how list comprehension works with counters so if anyone can help, that'd be great!

Comment: What is exactly `voc` there, and what you are trying to calculate is the mean ? or some kind of frequency meassure ?

Comment: In fact, I think more clarification is needed about what exactly is your input, the amount of values involved, and more examples. Your problem about seems interesting but is not completely clear, at least for me.

Comment: So I have a defaultdict (lm) of counters which maps strings to counters of (string -> counts) now the way they appear is that string is mapping to a count (integer), I want it to map to a probability instead (count of word in counter over sum of all the counts of words in the counter); the way this is done is by traversing every element in the counter and dividing its respective count over the sum of all the values in that counter. Does that make things clearer?

Comment: voc is basically a list which contains all the strings that are in the default dict, I'm guessing it's just another way of doing the dict.keys(). I am trying to replace all the present counters (which contain counts) with counters that contain probabilities (just normalizing every word inside that counter over the sum)

so if "hello" went to a counter which contained "h" ->3 and "i" -> 3 then I want that counter to be replaced by "h" 3/(3+3) = .5 and similarly for "i" ->.5

Comment: Improved code formatting